# How to convert a hexadecimal number into Ascii in C

Tags: c, ascii, hex

I plan to make a program like this:

```
loop

 read first character
 read second character

 make a two-digit hexadecimal number from the two characters
 convert the hexadecimal number into decimal
 display the ascii character corresponding to that number.

end loop
```

The problem I'm having is turning the two characters into a hexadecimal number and then turning that into a decimal number. Once I have a decimal number I can display the ascii character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you really want to write the conversion yourself, you can read the hex number with [f]scanf using the `%x` conversion, or you can read a string, and convert with (for one possibility) `strtol`.

If you do want to do the conversion yourself, you can convert individual digits something like this:

```
if (ixdigit(ch))
    if (isdigit(ch))
        value = (16 * value) + (ch - '0');
    else
        value = (16 * value) + (tolower(ch) - 'a' + 10);
else
    fprintf(stderr, "%c is not a valid hex digit", ch);
```

Comment: The code above works if there's only one digit. How would it be changed to deal with the first digit in a two-digit hex number?

Comment: @Z-buffer: for the most part, you just repeat for as many digits as necessary.

Comment: This works if 16 * value is removed, and then he result is multiplied by 16^n, where n is the position of the digit.

Answer (score 2):

```
char a, b;

...read them in however you like e.g. getch()

// validation
if (!isxdigit(a) || !isxdigit(b))
    fatal_error();

a = tolower(a);
b = tolower(b);

int a_digit_value = a >= 'a' ? (a - 'a' + 10) : a - '0';
int b_digit_value = b >= 'a' ? (b - 'a' + 10) : b - '0';
int value = a_digit_value * 0x10 + b_digit_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

put your two characters into a char array, null-terminate it, and use `strtol()` from '<stdlib.h>' ([docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strtol.html)) to convert it to an integer.

```
char s[3];

s[0] = '2';
s[1] = 'a';
s[2] = '\0';

int i = strtol(s, null, 16);
```